# What is the winter bash about? Confused by hats...

Tags: support, winter-bash

I read the posts regarding the Winter Bash but I still can not figure out what are the functions of these hats? I got one and have not clue of its uses. Please anyone could send me a link that explains how they work? their uses?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/

Comment: It's a trick to rid MSE of poor proofs. If you pull any proofs out  of your hat then your hat *and* your account will disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not 'useful', per se. They just attach to your avatar - they're cosmetic. (They also don't exist on Meta, apparently.) You can choose not to have your avatar 'wear' a hat, and also disable them entirely, in the "your hats" section in your profile on the main site - you can reach it through the snowflake icon in the black bar up top.

The main point is that they look rockin'.

Comment: And, the most unfortunate point is that they will disappear at the end of December (methinks... or at least by the end of winter)